# Is there a way to make jQuery output *actual markup*?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

When using jQuery to dynamically build markup, it sometimes becomes useful to have it return the actual HTML that it's generating as a string, rather than as a bunch of jQuery objects. Is there a way to do this? For example, here:

```
$("<strong></strong>").text("Hi there!");
```

I want to be able to extract the plain-text string

```
"<strong>Hi there!</strong>"
```

so that I can cache it remotely. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a outerHTML plugin for that. [Here is one](http://yelotofu.com/2008/08/jquery-outerhtml/):

```
jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function(s) {
    return (s)
    ? this.before(s).remove()
    : jQuery("<p>").append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
}
```

Usage:

```
alert($("<strong></strong>").text("foo").outerHTML());
// alerts <strong>foo</strong>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use the html() function

i.e.

```
$("").text("Hi There!").html();
```

Will return 'Hi There!'

Keep in mind this uses innerHTML, so

```
$("<div><b>Foo</b></div>").html();
```

will return

```
<b>Foo</b>
```

As a result you'll need to wrap your code in a surrounding div or span.

Answer (score 1):

Just call .html() to get HTML from any element, including generated ones. This is from a Chrome developer tool session:

```
> $("<div><span>blerg</span></div>")
Object
> $("<div><span>blerg</span></div>").html()
<span>blerg</span>
```

You can see, the first one returned an object, the second returns text.